# How can I seamlessly span single texture across multiple objects?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, texture-mapping

E.g. say I have any array of planes, that for texturing-specific purposes, I want to treat as a single 2d object. Like so:

[image: example]

How would I go about mapping this? (In production, the number of independent objects and their location in the world space is arbitrary.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple solution would be to adapt the technique of [Texture Atlases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texture_atlas) to your problem.

Remember that an entire texture is covered by the UV coordinate range of `[0,0],[1,1]`, and you may apply any subset of that range to a texture assignment. For the example provided in the question, each individual quad would cover a `0.25 x 0.25` subset of the original texture.

[image]

This of course can be scaled to an `n^2` number of objects, where each object covers a subset size of `1/n x 1/n` of the original texture. If utilizing the entire texture and/or keeping the subset textures square is not a requirement, then it can be scaled to any number of potential subset images.

Comment: Beautiful. I knew I was overthinking things. Thank your for your help.